# Combining the multiple records(rows) into single record(row)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to combine the multiple rows into a single row , i was able to get the half of it i tried many ways get the remaining half , below is the sql i wrote. any help will be appreciated.

```
DROP TABLE #TEST_DEPT_NAME 

CREATE TABLE #TEST_DEPT_NAME ([ID] [varchar](255) NULL,[CSN_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,[NOTE_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,[DEPARTMENT_NAME] [varchar](255) NULL,
[NOTE_CSN_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,[LINE] [varchar](50) NULL,[NOTE_TEXT] [nvarchar](max) NULL,[AUTHOR_USER_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,[AUTHOR_USER_NAME] [varchar](255) NULL,
[NOTE_TYPE_NAME] [varchar](255) NULL,[IS_ARCHIVED_YN] [varchar](255) NULL,[NOTE_STATUS_NAME] [varchar](255) NULL)

INSERT INTO #TEST_DEPT_NAME
VALUES ('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','001234' ,1 ,'NOTES_1.1' ,'1234','TEST','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','001234' ,1 ,'NOTES_1.1.1' ,'1234','TEST','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','0012345' ,2 ,'NOTES_1.2' ,'999999','TEST 1','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','00123456' ,3 ,'NOTES_1.3' ,'999999','TEST 1','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','66666' ,1 ,'NOTES_2.1' ,'1234','TEST','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','66666' ,2 ,'NOTES_2.2' ,'1234','TEST','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','66666' ,3 ,'NOTES_2.3' ,'1234','TEST','Clinic Note','N','Signed')


SELECT distinct  ID,[CSN_ID],[NOTE_ID],[DEPARTMENT_NAME],[NOTE_TYPE_NAME],[IS_ARCHIVED_YN]
,[NOTE_TEXT] =  (select ' '+ case when [NOTE_TEXT]= ''  then null else [NOTE_TEXT]end   from  #TEST_DEPT_NAME P1 
WHERE P1.[ID] = P2.[ID]AND P1.[CSN_ID] =P2.[CSN_ID] AND P1.NOTE_ID = P2.NOTE_ID AND P1.DEPARTMENT_NAME = P2.DEPARTMENT_NAME
AND P1.LINE = P2.LINE AND P1.NOTE_TYPE_NAME =P2.NOTE_TYPE_NAME AND P1.NOTE_CSN_ID = P2.NOTE_CSN_ID AND P1.IS_ARCHIVED_YN =P2.IS_ARCHIVED_YN  FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM #TEST_DEPT_NAME  P2 WHERE [ID] = '123456' 
GROUP BY ID,CSN_ID,[NOTE_ID],[DEPARTMENT_NAME],[NOTE_TYPE_NAME],[IS_ARCHIVED_YN],LINE,NOTE_CSN_ID
```

when i run above SQL i am getting result set as below

```
ID       CSN_ID  NOTE_ID    DEPARTMENT_NAME    NOTE_TEXT
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST               NOTES_1.1 NOTES_1.1.1
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST               NOTES_1.2
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST               NOTES_1.3
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST               NOTES_2.1
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST               NOTES_2.2
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST               NOTES_2.3
```

But I want the result as shown below

```
ID      CSN_ID  NOTE_ID     DEPARTMENT_NAME    NOTE_TEXT
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST               NOTES_1.1 NOTES_1.1.1 NOTES_1.2 NOTES_1.3
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST               NOTES_2.1 NOTES_2.2  NOTES_2.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using `left` and `stuff` functions with `group by`:

```
select t.ID ,t.CSN_ID,t.NOTE_ID,t.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
       STUFF((
        select ' ' + t1.NOTE_TEXT
        from #TEST_DEPT_NAME t1
        where t.ID =t1.ID  and t.CSN_ID=t1.CSN_ID and t.NOTE_ID=t1.NOTE_ID
              and t.DEPARTMENT_NAME=t1.DEPARTMENT_NAME 
              and left(t.NOTE_TEXT,8)=left(t1.NOTE_TEXT,8)
        for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') NOTE_TEXT_
from #TEST_DEPT_NAME t
group by t.ID ,t.CSN_ID,t.NOTE_ID,t.DEPARTMENT_NAME,left(t.NOTE_TEXT,8)
```

*Output:*

```
ID      CSN_ID  NOTE_ID     DEPARTMENT_NAME NOTE_TEXT_
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST            NOTES_1.1 NOTES_1.1.1 NOTES_1.2 NOTES_1.3
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST            NOTES_2.1 NOTES_2.2 NOTES_2.3
```

**Edit:** if you have more than 9 `NOTE_TEXT` I mean `NOTES_1..,NOTES_2...,NOTES_10...,NOTES_100...` then you have to use `charindex('.',t.NOTE_TEXT)` instead of `8` in above query:

```
select t.ID ,t.CSN_ID,t.NOTE_ID,t.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
       STUFF((
        select ' ' + t1.NOTE_TEXT
        from #TEST_DEPT_NAME t1
        where t.ID =t1.ID  and t.CSN_ID=t1.CSN_ID and t.NOTE_ID=t1.NOTE_ID
              and t.DEPARTMENT_NAME=t1.DEPARTMENT_NAME 
              and left(t.NOTE_TEXT,charindex('.',t.NOTE_TEXT))
                  =left(t1.NOTE_TEXT,charindex('.',t1.NOTE_TEXT))
        for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') NOTE_TEXT_
from #TEST_DEPT_NAME t
group by t.ID ,t.CSN_ID,t.NOTE_ID,t.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
         left(t.NOTE_TEXT,charindex('.',t.NOTE_TEXT))
```

Comment: You are assuming that the data is realistic data. One you start chopping up text fields and id fields for joins you are in for a world of hurt. Far better to use good design to make sure that the data is properly separated than make assumptions about field values.

In this case, there is a csn_note_id and a line field. In a good design one respresents all notes in a group and the other represents the lines of each note in a parent/child relationship. By incrementing csn_note_id when a line is created, you loose that relationship and can no longer group note lines together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is working fine until this issue found.                     if we look at the data in the table (ID,CSN_ID,NOTE_ID ,DEPT_NAME ) will have the same data , but when NOTE_CSN_ID changes LINE value changes and the NOTE_TEXT changes . the value in the LINE field is not consistent sometimes i get LINE 3 first into the data base then LINE 1 , I want the result set in LINE (1,2,3) order .can you please help me with this.

Comment: @user3311323 you are welcome, I didn't get you well, however you say _the value in the LINE field is not consistent_ so if you group by LINE either, then for sure you'll not get desired result because it has multiple values per any specific group in the your given desired output, but if you want to order by LINE you need to use it in the query (using subquery or you may want to concatenate lines) [see this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b78a/6) , hope these be useful

Comment: sorry for the confusion . here is what i am trying to do. Hope this will give more info 

i want the NOTE_TEXT to concatenate based on the value in the LINE(1,2,3) field 


example if i have data like this 

 ID  line   note_text
 1    1       A
 1    3       C
 1    2       B


I WANT THE RESULT SET AS 

ID  NOTE_TEXT
1   A B C

Comment: @user3311323, please clarify what you want, in above sample you have these `(id,line,note_text):(123456,1,NOTES_1.1),(123456,1,NOTES_1.1.1),(123456,2,NOTES_1.2),(123456,3,NOTES_1.3),(123456,1,NOTES_2.1),(123456,2,NOTES_2.2),(123456,3,NOTES_2.3)` so `on base of your recent comment` you want `(1,NOTES_1.1 NOTES_1.1.1 NOTES_1.2 NOTES_1.3 NOTES_2.1 NOTES_2.2 NOTES_2.3)` correct? try with creating a fiddle with sample data and desired output

Comment: @user3311323, I think you want to concatenate `NOTE_TEXT` on base of the `sort` of `LINE` so just sort them while concatenation(in the inner subquery) see [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b78a/8)

Comment: It did worked after removing the ID,NOTE_CSN_ID from the sub query order by list . Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Great, happy to see it worked for you finally. you are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that this is foley data and the values of Note_Text will actually be long-form notes inputted by users. The values in the note_csn_id field and inclusion of Line in the group by are causing the query to separate out the separate "Note_1" records.

Your query produces the following results in #test_dept_name:

```
ID      CSN_ID      NOTE_ID     DEPARTMENT_NAME     NOTE_CSN_ID     LINE    NOTE_TEXT       AUTHOR_USER_ID  AUTHOR_USER_NAME    NOTE_TYPE_NAME  IS_ARCHIVED_YN  NOTE_STATUS_NAME
123456  1234567     12345678    TEST                1234            1       NOTES_1.1       1234            TEST                Clinic Note     N               Signed
123456  1234567     12345678    TEST                1234            1       NOTES_1.1.1     1234            TEST                Clinic Note     N               Signed
123456  1234567     12345678    TEST                12345           2       NOTES_1.2       999999          TEST 1              Clinic Note     N               Signed
123456  1234567     12345678    TEST                123456          3       NOTES_1.3       999999          TEST 1              Clinic Note     N               Signed
123456  1234567     12345678    TEST                66666           1       NOTES_2.1       1234            TEST                Clinic Note     N               Signed
123456  1234567     12345678    TEST                66666           2       NOTES_2.2       1234            TEST                Clinic Note     N               Signed
123456  1234567     12345678    TEST                66666           3       NOTES_2.3       1234            TEST                Clinic Note     N               Signed
```

Notice that note_csn_id changes when a note line changes. This might be redundant behavior as you have a separate line number. We can make the query come out as you desire by:

- changing the group by clause to only consider the first X
  characters of note_csn_id (generally a bad idea as id fields tend to
  grow in length)
- changing how note_csn_id is populated to make it
  unique to each grouping of notes (the better idea if you have control over how note_csn_id is populated)

In either case you will need to also remove the join on Line from the sub-select and remove line from the group by clause.

If you are able to make the change to how note_csn_id is populated such that it looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO #TEST_DEPT_NAME
VALUES ('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','001234' ,1 ,'NOTES_1.1' ,'1234','TEST','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','001234' ,1 ,'NOTES_1.1.1' ,'1234','TEST','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','001234' ,2 ,'NOTES_1.2' ,'999999','TEST 1','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','001234' ,3 ,'NOTES_1.3' ,'999999','TEST 1','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','66666' ,1 ,'NOTES_2.1' ,'1234','TEST','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','66666' ,2 ,'NOTES_2.2' ,'1234','TEST','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
,('123456','1234567','12345678' ,'TEST','66666' ,3 ,'NOTES_2.3' ,'1234','TEST','Clinic Note','N','Signed')
```

Then you can change the select to the below:

```
SELECT distinct  
ID,
[CSN_ID],
[NOTE_ID],
[DEPARTMENT_NAME],
[NOTE_TYPE_NAME],
[IS_ARCHIVED_YN],
[NOTE_TEXT] =  (select ' '+ case when [NOTE_TEXT]= ''  then null else [NOTE_TEXT]end   from  #TEST_DEPT_NAME P1 
WHERE P1.[ID] = P2.[ID]AND P1.[CSN_ID] =P2.[CSN_ID] AND P1.NOTE_ID = P2.NOTE_ID AND P1.DEPARTMENT_NAME = P2.DEPARTMENT_NAME
 AND P1.NOTE_TYPE_NAME =P2.NOTE_TYPE_NAME AND P1.NOTE_CSN_ID = P2.NOTE_CSN_ID AND P1.IS_ARCHIVED_YN =P2.IS_ARCHIVED_YN  FOR XML PATH(''))

FROM #TEST_DEPT_NAME  P2 WHERE [ID] = '123456' 

GROUP BY ID,CSN_ID,[NOTE_ID],[DEPARTMENT_NAME],[NOTE_TYPE_NAME],[IS_ARCHIVED_YN],NOTE_CSN_ID
```

and get this result:

```
ID      CSN_ID  NOTE_ID     DEPARTMENT_NAME NOTE_TYPE_NAME  IS_ARCHIVED_YN  NOTE_TEXT
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST            Clinic Note     N                NOTES_1.1 NOTES_1.1.1 NOTES_1.2 NOTES_1.3
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST            Clinic Note     N                NOTES_2.1 NOTES_2.2 NOTES_2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this query is the desired one:

```
SELECT distinct  ID,[CSN_ID],[NOTE_ID],[DEPARTMENT_NAME],[NOTE_TEXT] =
(
select ' '+ case when [NOTE_TEXT]= ''  then null else [NOTE_TEXT]end
from  #TEST_DEPT_NAME P1 
WHERE P1.[ID] = P2.[ID]
AND P1.[CSN_ID] =P2.[CSN_ID] 
AND P1.NOTE_ID = P2.NOTE_ID 
AND P1.DEPARTMENT_NAME = P2.DEPARTMENT_NAME
AND P1.NOTE_TYPE_NAME =P2.NOTE_TYPE_NAME 
AND P1.IS_ARCHIVED_YN =P2.IS_ARCHIVED_YN  
AND SUBSTRING(P1.NOTE_TEXT, 0, CHARINDEX('.', P1.NOTE_TEXT)) = SUBSTRING(P2.NOTE_TEXT, 0, CHARINDEX('.', P2.NOTE_TEXT))
FOR XML PATH('')
)
FROM #TEST_DEPT_NAME  P2 WHERE [ID] = '123456' 
GROUP BY ID,CSN_ID,[NOTE_ID],[DEPARTMENT_NAME],[NOTE_TYPE_NAME],[IS_ARCHIVED_YN],LINE,NOTE_CSN_ID,SUBSTRING([NOTE_TEXT], 0, CHARINDEX('.', [NOTE_TEXT]))
```

Result:

```
ID      CSN_ID  NOTE_ID     DEPARTMENT_NAME    NOTE_TEXT
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST               NOTES_1.1 NOTES_1.1.1 NOTES_1.2 NOTES_1.3
123456  1234567 12345678    TEST               NOTES_2.1 NOTES_2.2  NOTES_2.3
```